# How can I find the Query ID for an Athena Saved Query on AWS console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

After I create a query in Athena using the AWS console, how can I find the Query ID associated with that query?

If I run the query and it fails, I can see the Query ID in the AWS console by going to "Recent Queries" and clicking the "Failed" link next to the query run (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying.html), but this doesn't work for queries where the status is "completed".

I can also use the API to first call [ListNamedQueries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/APIReference/API_ListNamedQueries.html), then iterate through that resulting list of query ids and call [GetNamedQuery](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/APIReference/API_GetNamedQuery.html) on each one to see if the name matches the query I'm looking for. But that's a really roundabout process just to get the query id for a query I just created.

Is there another way to simply find a named query's id via the console that I'm not seeing?

Comment: If query ran to success, then it's treated as "executed". You need to click on "Recent Queries" and look for execution ID, Query, Start Time, etc details. For a failed query, QueryID is same as ExecutionID .